# In Karate framework, Unable to get a value in an xml response through Parsing

Tags: karate

Working to project Karate as tool in my POC, 
This is the request I have - http://www.mocky.io/v2/5d7267732f00004a007d4cb1

and I used below code for Karate

```
Given url 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5d7267732f00004a007d4cb1'
When method GET
Then status 200 
Then print response
And match response == expectedoutput

* def val = $expectedoutput/Group/Elements/Group/Elements/Group[0]/Elements/Set
And print 'value is' , val
```

It is throwing an error -

> com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: userxmlDetails.feature:12
>   - xpath does not exist: /Group/Elements/Group/Elements/Group[0]/Elements/Set on expectedoutput
>     at ✽.* def val =
>   $expectedoutput/Group/Elements/Group/Elements/Group[0]/Elements/Set
>   (userxmlDetails.feature:12)

I also tried `expectedoutput/Group/Elements/Group/Elements/Group[0]/Elements/Set`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if the question seemed immature but I resolved it. We need to provide below

- def val = $expectedoutput/Group/Elements/Group/Elements/Group[1]/Elements/Set

Group[0] will not be accepted as indexing starts from 1 here.